# Problems installing visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

has anyone had problems installing visual studio?
I'm able to install the basic program but when I go on to install the ASP.NET and WebDevelopment packages I get the "Couldn't download sqlsyclrtypes" error.
Has anyone had the same problem in the past?

Deleted the sqlsyclrtypes file and copy pasted the package and still didnt work

Comment: VS Code or Enterprise?  Do you have enough disk space?  Is your OS Windows 10 or 11 if you are trying to install those SDKs?

Comment: @DaveS: Instead of "VS Code or Enterprise" you probably meant "VS Code" or "Visual Studio"? These are completely different applications. The "Enterprise" is just an edition of Visual Studio, along with "Community", "Professional", ... If you install Visual Studio, which version? Is it VS 2022?

Comment: I’ve tried 2022 and 2019. No luck with either